# what does the ":8" part mean in a Python f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  address_book = [{'name':'N.X.', 'addr':'15 Jones St', 'bonus': 70},
  {'name':'J.P.', 'addr':'1005 5th St', 'bonus': 400},
  {'name':'A.A.', 'addr':'200001 Bdwy', 'bonus': 5},]

  for person in address_book:
   print(f'{person["name"]:8} || {person["address"]:20} || {person["bonus"]:>5}')
```

what does :8,:20,:>5 mean?

Comment: That's part of an f-string. Notice the `f` in front of the string. Look it up and you'll find your answer. It's the format specification for that value. Same format used when calling `format()` on a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates that the value being printed should take at least 8 spaces (if the length of `person["name"]` is less than 8, it will be padded with spaces... the same applies to the `:20` and `:>5` on the `print` call... you can read more about f-strings here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings